# How to set up a Common Lisp development environment for OSX? (Programming Newbie)

Tags: macos, emacs, lisp, common-lisp

So, I am very new to programming. 
I would like to learn Common Lisp.
A few years ago, I used IDLE to write and run Python code. All it involved was downloading and installing one piece of software before I was ready to learn some Python.

With Common Lisp, things seem to be a lot more complex. I need to install:

- **GNU Emacs** - some sort of text editor which I have to run in Terminal
- **SBCL** - the compiler
- **SLIME** - an add-on to Emacs, which lets me code in Common Lisp (????)
- **Quicklisp**
- The list seems to go on forever

***Could somebody make this a simpler process for me to follow?***

I installed SBCL and emacs both with the help of Homebrew. Now I'm just trying to get SLIME to work with everything.

Following the instructions from this site
https://gist.github.com/CodeOmar/9477900#install-slime, I attempted to install quicklisp.
But I can't activate SLIME. When I launch emacs, [M-x package-install RET slime RET], it says 'no match'.

Answer this question like I'm an 8 year old, please.
If there is an easier way to set up a working Common Lisp environment, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: emacs uses lisp but isn't lisp. You can use any editor.

Comment: I installed Slime from quicklisp (`(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")`) after may failed attempts to do it manually.

Comment: Two years later: I suggest this list of [available editors](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html) and this [getting started guide](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html) on the Common Lisp Cookbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way, in my opinion, to approach Common Lisp in the Mac OS X environment, is to install from the Apple Store the fine [Clozure CL implementation](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/clozure-cl/id489900618?l=en&mt=12). It is a full implementation of standard ANSI Common Lisp with a very simple, Mac-friendly IDE. When you have mastered the language, you can install Emacs with Slime, and choose to stay with Clozure CL or pass to SBCL (or use some other implementation).

*Edited*

Another possibility is to go with the integrated environment provided by the free versions of the commercial implementations, either from Franz ([Allegro CL](http://franz.com/products/allegro-common-lisp/), Free Express Edition), or from LispWorks ([LispWorks personal edition](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html)). They have limitations, however, and Allegro CL requires a non immediate installation. Moreover, they are best used with some advanced knowledge of Common Lisp.

Comment: Note that Allegro CL does not offer a native Mac integrated environment. The integrated environment is based on X11 and Gtk. It's same as the one for Unix/Linux. Allegro CL has a native environment for MS Windows and X11/Gtk. Thus only Clozure CL and LispWorks support a native integrated environment on the Mac, based on Apple's Cocoa libraries.

Comment: @RainerJoswig you are right, but AllegroCL can be used also on Mac if XQuartz is installed.

Comment: You need to install GTK+, too. See: http://franz.com/support/documentation/10.0/doc/installation.htm#macosx-install-gtk-3
See also how to update to Mac OS X 10.10 and that Allegro CL must be non-SMP to run the IDE...
Basically nothing for a beginner...

Comment: This is installed automatically by Allegro CL at start time (see [documentation](http://franz.com/support/documentation/10.0/doc/installation.htm#macosx-install-1))

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I don't want to encourage this kind of question and answer, but in a comment I don't mind saying at all that I used LispWorks on OSX for a number of years, and was very pleased with it.  Moreover, I don't think it requires an advanced knowledge of Common Lisp; in some university courses, we recommended it to students in programming classes because it was so quick and easy to get up and running on the major desktop platforms (Windows, Linux, & OS X). That said, I use Emacs, SLIME, & CL-of-choice too, and it's worth the learning curve.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: full agreement. Plus: Additionally I also use Clozure CL with its native IDE.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a "batteries included" distribution that accompanied *Practical Common Lisp*. I don't think it's particularly current, but I could be wrong.

Here's how I set up my lemon oder Emacs environment; I have a similar installation for VIM and SLIMV. *Caveat:* I have several CL implementations installed in nonstandard places.

(a) Use git to clone the current SLIME (mine happens to be in `~/elisp/slime`, add your own seasoning to suite your tastes):

```
$ mkdir ~/elisp
$ cd ~/elisp
$ git clone https://github.com/slime/slime.git
```

(b) Add the following snippet to your .emacs:

```
;; Setup SLIME
;; Use the copy in my home directory.
(let ((my-slime-directory (expand-file-name "~/elisp/slime")))
(add-to-list 'load-path my-slime-directory)
(setq slime-backend (expand-file-name "swank-loader.lisp" my-slime-directory)))

;; If you installed your CL in a "standard place", such as /opt/local/bin,
;; you can delete the following form/6 lines. If you have multiple CLs installed,
;; this is an example of how you enumerate them; C-u M-x slime then lets
;; select one by name. Default is the first CL implementation in the list.
(setf slime-lisp-implementations
   `((ccl64 (,(expand-file-name "~/.local/bin/ccl64"))
             :env (,(concat "CCL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY=" (expand-file-name "~/ccl"))))
     (clisp ("clisp"))
     (ecl (,(expand-file-name "~/ecl-experimental/bin/ecl")))
     (sbcl (,(expand-file-name "~/.local/bin/sbcl")))))

;; Mac OSX owns C-up and C-down, so arrange for history
;; navigation to do something useful via C-c p and C-c n.
(eval-after-load 'slime
  `(progn
     (define-key slime-prefix-map "p" 'slime-repl-backward-input)
     (define-key slime-prefix-map "n" 'slime-reply-forward-input)))

;; Useful slime custribs
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-repl)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-autodoc)
(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-fancy)
```

(c) If you need or want MELPA, this is what you should have in your `.emacs`:

```
;; Package and MELPA package archive setup:
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
```

(d) Fire up Emacs and `M-x slime`.

HTH. :-)

Comment: Hmm. All I need is a good excuse to create a Docker template.